# I just wiped my computer and installed 16.04 LTS and I am not able to shut it down or restart

Tags: shutdown, 16.04

I just wiped my computer and installed 16.04 LTS and I am not able to shut it down or restart it just hangs in till I have to force shut down, by holding the power button.

Comment: how long did you wait for the restart/poweroff? The first time I shut down my computer after doing the upgrade it took a couple of minutes to shutdown, but now works as expected.

Comment: it took over a hour then i gave up on it

Comment: Prior to shutdown open a terminal and type: `systemctl start debug-shell` followed by your root pwd. When the shutdown or reboot hangs press escape to see behind the splash and then ctl+alt+F9 to enter vt9.  Once there enter `systemctl list-jobs`, then `systemctl --failed` I am unaware of a way to save this info to a file to upload here but you can take a pic.  I am curious if the swap partition failed to stop and timed out.  Please post pic or output data by editing your question.  Also you can hold alt+Sysrec while typing r,e,i,s,u,b, one letter at a time and the reboot will continue.

Answer (score 0):

Since the install appears to be a fresh install, you can reinstall it to the same partition in a non-destructive way that will insure the integrity of the system files.

To do this, run the Install and choose do something else for the install option.

Pick the partition where you performed the previous install.  Be sure not to check the `Format` box.  It will advise you that it will be deleting the old directories (/etc,/lib,/usr,/var, ...).  These are directories that have system and install files.  Your personal installed files such as /home and /usr/local/ will remain untouched.